# why this button is not showing up

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
const AddLayer = ({ layer }) => {
  return (
    <div>{({ handleChange }) => (
                 <button onClick={handleChange(props.index)}>
                  Save
                 </button>
    )} </div>
    
  )
};
  
export default AddLayer;
```

I use the above component as:

```
 <AddLayer addLayer={addLayer}></AddLayer>
```

Actually, I am working with next.js project and experimenting with building an app for creating an svg and manipulating text in it.
I am able to add a single line of text(circular) with editing features perfectly well.
I am new to React and want to expand this app to add several texts to svg with editing capabilities by navigating to and fro.
I learnt that it can be achieved by using the concept of *global context* and trying to use it but in vein.

[Image showing the working code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBRXv.jpg)
I am pasting my working code here:

## **svgEditor.js**

```
    import uuid from 'react-native-uuid';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import ArcText from '../models/ArcText'
    import { useState , useEffect, createContext, useContext, useReducer} from 'react';
    import React, { useRef} from 'react';
    import LayerContext from "./layerContext"
    import SaveLayerBtn from "./saveLayerBtn"
    import AddLayer from './addLayer'
    
    function RoundText({ id,title, sta, swa, rax, flip, children }) {   
        const arcText = new ArcText(title, sta, swa, 
            "125", "125",rax, rax,"1", flip);
            return (        
                <g  key = {id} id={id} fontSize='24' fontStyle='bold' fontFamily='Arial' fill='#345' stroke='none' position='absolute' fontWeight='bold' >
                { 
                   arcText.f_svg_text_arc().map(([x,y,r,c]) => {
                           return  <text  transform={`translate(${x}, ${y}) rotate(${r})`}> <tspan lengthAdjust="spacing" className="rtext">{c}</tspan> </text>
                   })
                 }            
                </g>    
            
            );
    }
          
    class SvgEditor {
        constructor(canvas, width=200, height=200) {      
          this.canvas = canvas;   
          this.temporaryId = SvgEditor.nextAutoIncrementedId;   
          SvgEditor.nextAutoIncrementedId += 1;
            
            const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            let newRect = document.createElementNS(svgns, "rect");
    
            newRect.setAttribute("x", "0");
            newRect.setAttribute("y", "0");
            newRect.setAttribute("width", "250");
            newRect.setAttribute("height", "250");
            newRect.setAttribute("fill", "none");
            
            canvas.appendChild(newRect);
            
            let circle = document.createElementNS(svgns, "circle");
    
            circle.setAttribute("cx", "125");
            circle.setAttribute("cy", "125");
            circle.setAttribute("r", "123");        
            circle.setAttribute("fill", "none");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke", "#2f69c2");
            circle.setAttribute("stroke-width", "2");
    
            canvas.appendChild(circle);
        }
    }

SvgEditor.nextAutoIncrementedId = 0;

export default function Editor(){   
    const rsvg = useRef("svg");
    const [layers, setLayers] = useState(LayerContext);
    
    const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(0);
    const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(359);
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);
    const [flip,setFlip] = useState(false);
    const [radiusX, setRadiusX] = useState(100);
    const [keyValue, setKeyValue] = useState(uuid.v4());
    const [firstValue, setFirstValue] = useState(0);
    const [secondValue, setSecondValue] = useState(180);
    const [thirdValue, setThirdValue] = useState(100);
    const [titleValue, setTitleValue] = useState("Some Text");
    const textArr = [] ;
    const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
    
    const handleContextChange = selected_ind => {
        this.setState({selected_ind});
    };
    
    useEffect(() => {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('RoundText');  
        new SvgEditor(canvas, 250, 250);        
        updateLayer();
        
    },[]);
    
    const deleteLayer = (id) => {
        setLayers(prevLayer => {
            return prevLayer.filter(layer => layer.id != id)
        })
        
    }
    const updateLayer = () =>{
        setLayers([{keyValue,titleValue,firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue, flip}]);
    }
    const addLayer = (title="some text here") => {
        setLayers(prevLayers => {
        return [[{id: uuid.v4(), titleValue:title}], ...prevLayers];
        })
    }
    
    return (
        <div>       
          {JSON.stringify(layers[0])}   
        <div className="row">
              <div className="col-6">
                    <svg id="RoundText" ref={rsvg} viewBox='0 0 250 250' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='250' height='250'>
                       <RoundText key={keyValue} title={titleValue} sta={firstValue} swa={secondValue} rax = {thirdValue} flip={flip}/>
                    </svg>
              </div>
              <div className="col-6">
               <AddLayer addLayer={addLayer}></AddLayer>
               <section className="range-slider">   
        <input type="text" value={titleValue} placeholder="Type some text here" onChange={event => {setTitleValue(event.target.value);updateLayer();}} />
        <input type="range" value={firstValue} min={minValue} max={maxValue} 
                step={step}  onChange={event => {setFirstValue(event.target.value);updateLayer();}} /> 
        <input type="range" value={secondValue} min={minValue} max={maxValue} step={step} onChange={event => {setSecondValue(event.target.value);updateLayer();}} />
        <input type="range" value={thirdValue} min={minValue} max="150" step={step} onChange={event => {setThirdValue(event.target.value);updateLayer();}} />                
        <input type="checkbox"  onChange={()=>{setFlip(!flip);setFirstValue(0);updateLayer(); }}/>
        
        </section>   
             <SaveLayerBtn/>
              </div>
        </div>       
        </div>
    );
}
```

## **ArcText.js**

```
const cos = Math.cos,
    sin = Math.sin,
    pi = Math.PI,
    abs = Math.abs;
    
class ArcText {
    constructor(text,sta, swa, cx = 125,cy = 125,rx = 98,ry = 98,rot = 0,flip = false){     
        this.temporaryId = ArcText.nextAutoIncrementedId;
        ArcText.nextAutoIncrementedId += 1;     
        this.text = text;
        this.flip = flip;
        this.charArr = this.setCharArr(this.text,this.flip) ;
        this.centerX  = parseFloat(cx);
        this.centerY = parseFloat(cy);
        this.radiusX = parseFloat(rx);
        this.radiusY = parseFloat(ry);
        this.sweepAngle = parseFloat(swa);
        this.rotAngle = parseFloat(rot);
        
        this.startAngle =  (sta > 0)? parseFloat(sta) : this.setDefStartAngle(this.flip)
        
    }

    f_matrix_times([[a, b], [c, d]], [x, y]) { 
        return [a * x + b * y, c * x + d * y];
    }

    f_rotate_matrix (x){
        const cosx = cos(x);
        const sinx = sin(x);
        return [[cosx, -sinx], [sinx, cosx]];
    }
    
    f_vec_add([a1, a2], [b1, b2]) { return [a1 + b1, a2 + b2]}
    
    f_svg_text_arc() {
        const txt = this.text;
        const charArr = this.charArr; 
        const cx = this.centerX;
        const cy = this.centerY;
        const rx = this.radiusX;
        const ry = this.radiusY;
        const stan = this.startAngle; 
        const swan = this.sweepAngle;
        const rot = this.rotAngle;
        const flip = this.flip;
        var tvals = [];
        var tl = txt.length;
        var sta = stan / 180 * pi;
        var dd =  (swan / tl ) /180 * pi;
        var swa = swan / 180 * pi;
        swa = swa % (2 * pi); 
        const rotMatrix = this.f_rotate_matrix(rot / 180 * pi);
        
        for(var i=0;i< tl; i++){ 
             const [sX, sY] = (this.f_vec_add(this.f_matrix_times(rotMatrix, [rx * cos(sta), ry * sin(sta)]), [cx, cy]));
             var r = (!flip) ? (sta * 180 / pi) + 90 : (sta * 180 / pi) + 270;
             tvals[i] = [sX, sY, r ,charArr[i]]
             let f = (!flip) ? 1 : -1;
             sta = sta + f * dd;
        }
        
        return tvals;
    };  
    
    setDefStartAngle(flip){
        var tl = this.text.length;
        var sta;
        var swa = (this.sweepAngle > 0) ? this.sweepAngle : 360 / tl;
        this.sweepAngle = swa;
        if(!flip)  
           sta = (swa <= 180 ) ? 180 + (180 - swa ) / 2 : 180 - (swa - 180) / 2;
        else
            sta = (swa <= 180 ) ? 180 - (180 - swa ) / 2 : 180 + (swa - 180) / 2;       
        return sta;
    }
    
    setCharArr(text = "", flip = false) {
        return  [...text];
        
    }
}

module.exports = ArcText;
```

## **LayerContext.js**

```
import { createContext, Component } from "react";

const LayerContext = createContext(
                {layers: [],
                setLayers: () => {
                    
                },
                });

export default LayerContext;
```

## **SaveLayerBtn.js**

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import LayerContext from "./layerContext";

const SaveLayerBtn = (props) => {
  const context = useContext(LayerContext);
  return (
        <div>{({ handleChange }) => (
                 <button onClick={handleChange(props.index)}>
                  Save
                 </button>
            )}
            
        </div>
  );
};

export default SaveLayerBtn;
```

## **AddLayer.js**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
const AddLayer = ({addLayer}) => {
  return (
    <div>{(
            <button onClick={addLayer}>
                  Add Text
            </button>
    )} </div>
    
  )
};
  
export default AddLayer;
```

## **index.js**

```
 <Editor width="250" height="250">
         </Editor>
```

Comment: because you provide function, not element

Comment: Your context of the handleChange function is missing. You should add that for further help.

Comment: @BenjaminK I have updated the detail requirement with code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You are having a function inside your return statement

```
({handleChange}) => ()
```

Your context of the `handleChange` function is missing in your question, so I can't help you with that. As I don't know where it's coming from.

But to show your button simply use it as an element instead of a function.

```
return (
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => handleChange(props.index)}>Save</button>
  </div>
)
```

Also to avoid and infinite loop you should call the onClick function with an arrow function `() => handleChange(props.index)`